# Weak closure of the unit sphere in $\ell^p$ is the unit ball?

Tags: functional-analysis, lp-spaces, weak-convergence

> Let $1<p<\infty$ and $x\in \ell^p$ with $\|x\|_p\le 1$. Then there exists a sequence $(x_n)$ with $\|x_n\|_p=1$ such that $x_n\to x$ weakly.

**My attempt:** By Riesz lemma, there exists a sequence $(z_n)$ such that $\|z_n-z_m\|_p\ge \frac12$ and $\|z_n-x\|\ge \frac12$ for all $m\ne n$. Moreover, as $\ell^p$ is reflexive, so $(z_n)$ has a weakly convergent subsequence, say $(z_{n_k})$.

> I don't know how to proceed.

**Edit:** If $z$ is the weak limit of a $(z_{n_k})$, then the sequence $y_k=z_{n_{k+1}}-z_{n_{k}}+x$ converges weakly to $x$. But the normalized sequence $\left(\frac{y_k}{\|y_k\|}\right)$ might not converge weakly to $x$, right?

Comment: The title should be:  the weak closure of the unit sphere is the unit ball. Each weak neighbourhood of $x$ , $\|x\|<1,$ is unbounded therefore it intersects the unit sphere.

Comment: Or rather weak *sequential* closure

Comment: @RyszardSzwarc Yes, sorry for the typo

Comment: @AnneBauval In this case sequential as the unit ball is metrizable in the weak topology.

Comment: Hint : call $e_n$ the sequence with an $1$ at position $n$ an other entries equal to $0$. Show that for every bounded sequence $(\alpha_n)$ of real numbers, the sequence $(\alpha_n e_n)$ converges weakly to $0$.

Comment: @ChristopheLeuridan Okay, I can show that, but how to use it?

Comment: Add such a sequence to $x$, choosing the $\alpha_n$ in such a way that you get a sequence of vectors on the unit sphere of $\ell^p$.

Comment: @ChristopheLeuridan I'm not able to see why existence of such a sequence is guaranteed.

Comment: Given $x$ in the unit ball and a positive integer $n$, $||x+\lambda e_n||_p^p$ is a continuous function of $\lambda$, which goes to infinity as $\lambda$ goes to infinity...